# trying to get rid of string in column

Tags: pandas

```
bank['aon'].apply(lambda x : x == np.nan if bank[bank['aon'].str.contains('UA')] else x)
```

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vectorial operation with `mask`:

```
bank['aon'] = bank['aon'].mask(bank['aon'].str.contains('UA'))
```